# Wildcard variable for firestore security not working as expected

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

This is the basic security rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /patients/{patientId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == patientId;
    }
  }
}
```

And I pass the same auth.uid that already exists in the patients collection. But the firestore security emulator denies this rule as request.auth.uid does not match with patientId. Patient id wildcard variable returns "{patientId}" which does not match with the document id string that I pass in auth.uid

Comment: Please edit the question to show the app code that makes the request.  Without that, wek can't see if you might be doing something wrong.  Be sure to show exact values so we know exactly the values in use here.